# CakePhp 3.x Continue session from out of the app

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm building a **new version of a website in cakephp 3.x**. Since I rebuild in phases,I need interaction between parts of the new site and the old site. The best way to do this at this moment is with the use of **$_SESSION**.
My problem is that the cakephp part makes a new session instead of using the active one from the native PHP part. It writes it next to it in the same folder.

this is my app.php setting in cakephp

```
 'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => '2000',
 'ini' => [
     'session.cookie_domain' => '.domain.com',
     'session.save_path' => '/var/www/clients/web/tmp',
     'session.name' => 'PHPSESSID'
 ]
],
```

These are my php.ini settings

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user memcache memcached
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/www/clients/web/tmp    /var/www/clients/web/tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session.name` ini option gets overwritten by the session configs `cookie` option if it is set (which it will be by default in case the `defaults` option is is set).

By default the session class instance is being [**created via `Session::create()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.5/src/Network/Request.php#L184), consuming your session configuration, and then inheriting the corresponding CakePHP session defaults in case the `defaults` optin is being used. All of the available defaults do define the `cookie` option, which has a value of `CAKEPHP`. The `php` defaults currently looks like

```
'cookie' => 'CAKEPHP',
'ini' => [
    'session.use_trans_sid' => 0,
]
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.5/src/Network/Session.php#L131-L136**

The `cookie` option, when present, will overwrite the `session.name` ini option in the [**session class' constructor**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.5/src/Network/Session.php#L202-L204), and thus your `PHPSESSID` setting gets lost, and consequently the existing session is not going to be picked up.

## tl;dr - Use the `cookie` option, or do not inherit defaults

So, you could either use  the `cookie` option instead of `session.name`

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID',
    'timeout' => '2000',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.domain.com',
        'session.save_path' => '/var/www/clients/web/tmp'
    ]
],
```

or do not inherit the defaults, and define everything necessary on your own

```
'Session' => [
    'timeout' => '2000',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.domain.com',
        'session.save_path' => '/var/www/clients/web/tmp',
        'session.name' => 'PHPSESSID',
        'session.use_trans_sid' => 0
    ]
],
```

Comment: The cookie option did the trick! Thank you for this clear response.